# UNC path or mapped drive or

Tags: web-services, windows-server

In our company we have a Windows Server 2008 running on an external location. We can use everything on that server via RDP. This server is used to run IIS, and ASP.NET on it. applications

I would like to know if the following is possible:

- map a networkdrive, (K: for example) or connect via UNC path by logging in with C#/ASP.NET
- show images which are stored in a document library on sharepoint to users which aren't logged in (via stream) [[this works if I can login somehow! I've tried this on my local machine where I could login site.sharepoint.com]]

Comment: Im trying out SyncToy now from Microsoft. Syncing mapped drive to local folder which can be shared on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order  to be able to map it as network connection you would need to ensure that WebDav protocol is properly working on both the SharePoint Server and your clients, besides the Server being accessible to clients, obviously.

The simplest way to test would be to connect via Web Browser to your SharePoint Library and using tab Library - "Open with Windows Explorer" - see what it gives you. - check this step by step to get you started http://mossdefinitely.blogspot.ch/2010/08/enabling-webdav-in-sharepoint-windows.html

If that works, than you could map it (although it might require occasional authentication unless Kerberos is in place already)!

Comment: And how can I map a folder without being logged in? The remote server has no logged in accounts which is logged in forever.

Comment: Each user accessing SharePoint server would usually have its own account. Otherwise mapping would compromise SharePoint's security, e.g. using always a service account to map-it automatically to every single user would create holes in security.

Comment: So there is basically no solution to have the server map to sharepoint without logging in as a user.
The website I'm creating need access to sharepoint (consider that as the user) and the information on the sharepoint will be streamed to the browser.
Not possible at all?

Comment: By using a single "Service Account" for everyone, but not recommended really.